# How to declare font-face fonts using styled-components MUI?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have an implementation via 'vanilla' styled-components:
Here is a code:

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components';

export const GlobalFonts = createGlobalStyle`
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Inter';
    src: url('app/fonts/Inter-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
  }
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Inter';
    src: url('app/fonts/Inter-Medium.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: normal;
  }
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Inter';
    src: url('app/fonts/Inter-SemiBold.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: normal;
  }
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Inter';
    src: url('app/fonts/Inter-Bold.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: normal;
  }
  
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Archivo';
    src: url('app/fonts/Archivo-SemiBold.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: normal;
  }
`;
```

But it does not applicable for me to use vanilla styled-components, I need to use material-ui:
looks like something similar to this:
https://mui.com/material-ui/api/global-styles/

But I don't know how to correctly define it because each property of 'style object' should be unique, but here is '5 font-face' properties.

I would be grateful if someone watch the good solution for this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it in this way:

```
import GlobalStyles from '@mui/material/GlobalStyles';
import * as React from 'react';

export const Inter400 = (
    <GlobalStyles
        styles={{
            '@font-face': {
                fontFamily: 'Inter',
                src: `url('app/fonts/Inter-Regular.ttf') format('truetype')`,
                fontWeight: 400,
                fontStyle: 'normal',
            },
        }}
    />
);

export const Inter500 = (
    <GlobalStyles
        styles={{
            '@font-face': {
                fontFamily: 'Inter',
                src: `url('app/fonts/Inter-Medium.ttf') format('truetype')`,
                fontWeight: 500,
                fontStyle: 'normal',
            },
        }}
    />
);
export const Inter600 = (
    <GlobalStyles
        styles={{
            '@font-face': {
                fontFamily: 'Inter',
                src: `url('app/fonts/Inter-SemiBold.ttf') format('truetype')`,
                fontWeight: 600,
                fontStyle: 'normal',
            },
        }}
    />
);

export const Inter700 = (
    <GlobalStyles
        styles={{
            '@font-face': {
                fontFamily: 'Inter',
                src: `url('app/fonts/Inter-Bold.ttf') format('truetype')`,
                fontWeight: 700,
                fontStyle: 'normal',
            },
        }}
    />
);

export const Archivo = (
    <GlobalStyles
        styles={{
            '@font-face': {
                fontFamily: 'Archivo',
                src: `url('app/fonts/Archivo-SemiBold.ttf') format('truetype')`,
                fontWeight: 600,
                fontStyle: 'normal',
            },
        }}
    />
);

export const GlobalFonts = [Inter400, Inter500, Inter600, Inter700, Archivo];
```

and in `App.tsx` just did `GlobalFonts.map(font=> font)`